# Check/Resolve cross-references in separate xml files

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

### Starting point

Let's say we have a book in xml format. This book consists of many assets and these can reference each other by a tag `ref-asset` with attribute `path`. [Path-Mask: *{id}|{version}* of target-asset].

Important: Assets are single files and there is no merged, complete file.

**Exemplary XML** (merged for better visual view)

```
<book>
    <!-- file a.xml -->
    <asset id="1" version="1.0">
        <name>Prolog</name>
    </asset>
    <!-- file b.xml -->
    <asset id="2" version="2">
        <name>Table of content</name>
        <list>
            <item><ref-asset path="1|1.0">Prolog</ref-asset></item>
            <item><ref-asset path="2|2.0">Table of content</ref-asset></item>
            <item><ref-asset path="3|1.1">FooBar</ref-asset></item>
        </list>
    </asset>
    <!-- file c.xml -->
    <asset id="3" version="1.1">
        <name>FooBar</name>
    </asset>
</book>
```

### Request

- Check all `ref-asset` if linked target is in `book`.
- Create report about results [exists, not exists, asset exists but wrong version, ...]
- [in addition: Replace the reference with the content of target.]

### Settings

- Saxon 9.6.x EE XSLT 2.0
- Java
- 100 up to x thousand single documents (combined filesize: upper 3 digit Mb)

#### How to solve

**First attempt** function [collection()](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!functions/fn/collection) + function [document()](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!functions/fn/document):

Search for all single asset-files on filesystem via collection(), load them into process via document() and search for matching hits.

**Second attempt** Merged, complete File:

Merge all single `assets` into `book` and match via `xsl:key` or similiar techniques.

---

### Question(s)

- Is `collection()` capable of loading thousands of documents and still perform well with a followed `document()` to process the asset?
- How to "index" run-timed loaded documents [still via `xsl:key`?] to search efficiently?

Further hints are highly appreciated / No specific stylsheet needed [i will do it on my own, as soon as i know what way to go].

---

EDITs: `collection()` returns already a sequence of document nodes, so `document()` might be unnecessary.

Comment: `collection` already gives you a sequence of document nodes so I currently don't understand what you additionally need the `document` function for. As for memory concerns with collections of files and Saxon EE, see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!functions/saxon/discard-document, that should help. I haven't understood how your input data looks as you first say "there is no merged, complete file" and then as an example input present something named "merged file".

Comment: the fact `collection()` returns a sequence of document nodes is new to me. i am a beginner in that field. the "merged, complete file" is just for better overview. as i mentioned, the files are splitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions about performance are always product-dependent, so it would be easier to answer if the question were Saxon-specific.

I have often used the collection() function in Saxon to process thousands of input documents, and yes, it is quite capable of doing this. In Saxon-EE, collection() is multi-threaded so you can be parsing multiple documents in parallel on a multi-core machine.

Indexing is a bit tricky because the key() function can only search one document. We studied a very similar problem during the performance workshop at the Oxford XML Summer School a couple of weeks ago, and solved the problem (getting a ten-fold speed-up) by using the new XSLT 3.0 feature of maps. Something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="index" as="map(xs:string, element(asset))">
  <xsl:map>
    <xsl:for-each select="collection('....')/asset">
      <xsl:map-entry key="@id || '|' || @version"
                     select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:map>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="ref-asset">
  <xsl:variable name="asset" select="$index(@path)"/>
  ....
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I will look forward to XML Prague 2016 and hope *xsl:map* will be part of it.

Answer (score 2):

I have written an npm package to resolve references in xml. Hope it serves your purpose
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-path-resolver.
This package would take the xml and return JSON with resolved paths

#### CODE USAGE

```
const xmlPathResolver = require("xml-path-resolver");
const xmlString = `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<note id="1212"  importance="high" logged="true" x_note="23">
    <title>Happy</title>
     <todo>Work</todo>
     <todo>Play</todo>
</note>
<note id="23" importance="high" logged="true">
</note>
<note importance="high" logged="true">
</note>
<person x_note="1212">
</person>
`;
const resolvedJSON = xmlPathResolver(xmlString,{ crossReference: /x_(.*)/ });
```

Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<note id="1212"  importance="high" logged="true" x_note="23">
    <title>Happy</title>
     <todo>Work</todo>
     <todo>Play</todo>
</note>
<note id="23" importance="high" logged="true">
</note>
<note importance="high" logged="true">
</note>
<person x_note="1212">
</person>
```

The above xml has cross reference paths, The resolved JSON output is

```
{
  "_declaration": {
    "_attributes": {
      "version": "1.0",
      "encoding": "utf-8"
    }
  },
  "note": [
    {
      "_attributes": {
        "id": "1212",
        "importance": "high",
        "logged": "true",
        "x_note": {
          "_attributes": {
            "id": "23",
            "importance": "high",
            "logged": "true"
          }
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "_text": "Happy"
      },
      "todo": [
        {
          "_text": "Work"
        },
        {
          "_text": "Play"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_attributes": {
        "id": "23",
        "importance": "high",
        "logged": "true"
      }
    },
    {
      "_attributes": {
        "importance": "high",
        "logged": "true"
      }
    }
  ],
  "person": {
    "_attributes": {
      "x_note": {
        "_attributes": {
          "id": "1212",
          "importance": "high",
          "logged": "true",
          "x_note": {
            "_attributes": {
              "id": "23",
              "importance": "high",
              "logged": "true"
            }
          }
        },
        "title": {
          "_text": "Happy"
        },
        "todo": [
          {
            "_text": "Work"
          },
          {
            "_text": "Play"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```